# cannot edit my textarea

Tags: html, textarea

I create a textarea in my html code but I cannot edit the text in it in the webpage. What can be the reason? 
Here is my code:

```html
<div class="field-group">
    <div class="field">
        <textarea rows="20" cols="70" class="relative" id="myTextarea">
               Welcome!!
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I turned your code into a snippet, if you click on "Run code snippet" you'll see that it works just fine. You'll have to show more of your code. Please edit the question so that the snippet shows the problem you're having. The most common cause is that there's another element overlapping the textarea so that you can't click on it, but without seeing a working example it's impossible to say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you missed, I added HTML tag and it is working fine for me. I hope that it will work for you also.

```
<html>
 <body>
   <div class="field-group">
    <div class="field">
      <textarea rows="20" cols="70" class="relative" id="myTextarea">
        Welcome!!
      </textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```